# How to use "getMouse() & getMouseNow()" and which file contain these functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, zelle-graphics

I used Zelle's "graphics.py" file. I use Thonny. I want
to use function "getMouse() & getMouseNow()", but these messages come up. What should I do ? Help Me !

Code :

```
from graphics import *

def draw():
    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 500, 500)
    circle = Circle(Point(150,150), 50)
    circle.draw(win)
    p = win.getMouse()
    x = p.x
    y = p.y
    circle.moveTo(x,y)

draw()
```

Output :

Creates a window of above dimensions and a circle in it.
After clicking into the window ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Shivam\Documents\Python\Mouse.py", line 13, in <module>
        draw()
    File "C:\Users\Shivam\Documents\Python\Mouse.py", line 10, in draw
        m = Circle.moveTo(x,y)
AttributeError: type object 'Circle' has no attribute 'moveTo'
```

Comment: Please copy the code and the error message into the question, it helps in case image provider becomes unavailable.

Comment: Okay, I've put it now.

Answer (score 2):

getMouse() function return an instance of Point (http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py), from which you can extract x and y. You can use for example :

```
p = win.getMouse()
x = p.x
y = p.y
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank You ! This worked for me, but now another problem has taken place. It says : AttributeError : type object 'Circle' has no attribute 'moveTo'

Comment: I checked in the module and I don't find any **moveTo()** function. There is a **move()** function but it takes a _dx_, _dy_ as input. That means you have to subtract the current position of the circle to your mouse position.

Comment: Does it mean there should be another module having 'moveTo()' ? If you find it, please share. Thanks !

Comment: @Shivam `def moveTo(p, x, y): p.move(x - p.x, y - p.y)`

Comment: Thank you, I had my exams so I didn't reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `moveTo()` method and you don't need one, the `move()` method should do what you want if you make the movement relative to the object's center position:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("My Circle", 500, 500)

# ...

circle = Circle(Point(150, 150), 50)
circle.draw(win)

# ...

while True:
    point = win.getMouse()
    center = circle.getCenter()
    circle.move(point.x - center.x, point.y - center.y)
```

Comment: Thank you,  I had my exams so I didn't reply.